# What is the difference between Row and RowLayout?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

This works as intended with `Row`, but not with `RowLayout`. Why? What is the difference between the two?

```
ApplicationWindow {    
    title: "Testing"
    width: 640
    height: 480

    //RowLayout {
    Row {        
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: rect1
            width: parent.width * 0.3
            height: parent.height
            color: "blue"
        }
        Rectangle {
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width * 0.7
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have more options using `RowLayout` like alignment. But it is preferred to use `Row` because performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QML Row vs. RowLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914785/qml-row-vs-rowlayout)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Row` is a [Item Positioner](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-layouts.html). Positioner items are container items that manage the positions of items in a declarative user interface.

`RowLayout` is part of [Qt Quick Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html). They manage both the positions and the sizes of items on a declarative user interface, and are well suited for resizable user interfaces.

Your code with `RowLayout` should look like this:

```
RowLayout{
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 0
    Rectangle{
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width * 0.3
        color: "blue"
    }
    Rectangle{
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: As an additional answer to Meefte's. Row is [Item Positioners](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-layouts.html), RowLayout is [Qt Quick Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html). They behave in a similar way, but have two difference: - Item Positioners are also containers in their own right.
- Qt Quick Layouts can resize their items.

Comment: While it's the only answer, I don't feel this is a helpful answer. It just copies the documentation, which arguably does nothing to demystify the difference, so hence this questions. `Row` is an 'item positioner'. So what? `RowLayout` is part of QT Quick Layouts. Well, `Row` is also part of QTQuick. What are the ACTUAL and FUNDAMENTAL differences in concept and use?!?!

Answer (score 1):

I think

`Row` is a container which grows the size based on the children of `Row`, making them line up as a row, so the children of it shall have size.

`RowLayout` is the wrapper of its children, giving them the ability of row positioning and resizing based on the size of `RowLayout`, so `RowLayout` shall have its own size to help the children to position and resize.